# Android Camerax colapsa con grabaciones periodicas

Tags: android-studio

Estoy haciendo un programa que realiza grabaciones de forma periódica de 2sg cada 10 sg usando camerax versión 1.4.1

En cada grabación lanzo  los metodos startcamera, recording  y release camera .
El problema es que la actividad colapsa a las 24h de funcionamiento

Pienso que no hago una buen cierre de la cámara y genero memory leaks